# Spring mongoTemplate only fetch part of document in model

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongotemplate

**Background:**
I want to fetch part of a model without include all fields in that document.

**Problem:** All fields get included in the response model. Even if they are null, they're there.

**Question:** How do exclude fields completely from the response model?

Model:

```
@Document
public class Business {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private Location location;
    private String image;
    //Getters and setters
}
```

Repository:

```
 public List<Business> findAllMapPinsByLocation(Circle circle) {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.fields().include("location");
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("location").withinSphere(circle));
    return mongoTemplate.find(query, Business.class, "business");
  }
```

Response:

```
[{
    "id": "57fcb673531ff7432e0edf97",
    "title": null,
    "location": {
        "longitude": 14.026884101506173,
        "latitude": 66.11196822800929
    },
    "image": null,
}]
```

This is how I want the response to look like. All fields without id and location are removed from the model:

```
[{
    "id": "57fcb673531ff7432e0edf97",
    "location": {
        "longitude": 14.026884101506173,
        "latitude": 66.11196822800929
    }
}]
```

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with spring mongo db, you can set `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL` on your class to avoid null values, haven't tried. Let me know if it works

Comment: No @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) won't solve my issue because I want fields to be able to be null when fetching a complete Business model.

Comment: If I understand you correctly,  you want to mention exclusions in the criteria it self?

Comment: Since you have to map the JSON returned by Mongo into a Java object, you'll always end up with `null` values in your object no matter if they are in the JSON. What's the point of excluding them in the JSON ? Or I'm missing something ?

Comment: Pragnani, yes that's correct!

Comment: Gaël J. To get a more clean response model without unnecessary data.